# Hex Entity Encoding in SQLmap

Tags: python, xml, encoding, hex, sqlmap

I am using SQLmap and want to hex-entity-encode the input before SQLmap sends it to the server.

For example, hex-entity-encoding of `"abc"` should return `&#x61;&#x62;&#x63;`

I know that I should use a python tamper script which should hex-entity-encode the given input. But I don't know how I could hex-entity-encode data in Python.

May someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Apply [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (also called *f-strings* for short) e.g. as follows:

```
a_string = 'abc Trường An Tô Nguyễn'
''.join([f'&#x{ord(ch):x};' for ch in a_string])
# '&#x61;&#x62;&#x63;&#x20;&#x54;&#x72;&#x1b0;&#x1edd;&#x6e;&#x67;&#x20;&#x41;&#x6e;&#x20;&#x54;&#xf4;&#x20;&#x4e;&#x67;&#x75;&#x79;&#x1ec5;&#x6e;'
```

or e.g. (see [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language))

```
''.join([f'&#x{ord(ch):04x};' for ch in a_string])
#'&#x0061;&#x0062;&#x0063;&#x0020;&#x0054;&#x0072;&#x01b0;&#x1edd;&#x006e;&#x0067;&#x0020;&#x0041;&#x006e;&#x0020;&#x0054;&#x00f4;&#x0020;&#x004e;&#x0067;&#x0075;&#x0079;&#x1ec5;&#x006e;'
```